# extensive vs intensive labor in US in recent decades

Tags: labor-economics, business-cycles

Total Hours worked is a mix of extensive (to work or not, the usual standard working week) and intensive (how many hours to work).

I'm interested in how this balance of extensive and intensive margins worked in the US over time, particularly from the 1980s onwards, and over the financial crisis.

Can anyone suggest a source carrying out such an analysis?

Comment: US BLS should have info on labor force participation rates and hours worked. The Federal Reserve (FRED) probably ties into this data & has a pretty easy interface.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://ftp.iza.org/dp6051.pdf) should serve as a starting point, although it's too early to cover the crisis. Maybe you'll find something when looking in papers citing this one via Google Scholar.